# Check all does not work in jQuery version 2.1.3

Tags: jquery

Why is `Check all` not working when I use jQuery version 2.1.3, check [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/usxvb6rb/)

This code was working fine with 1.7.4. May be toggle is not supported in 2.1.3 version and i tried with `on.click` but not getting the expected result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
        $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $(this).val('check all');  
        $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
    }),
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    $("#count").html($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length + " item(s) selected")
    })
})
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From JQuery guide](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on ".toggle()"

> Display or hide the matched elements.

Here a solution with new plugin:

```
$.fn.newtoggle = function(on,off){ 
    return this.each(function() {
        var toggleClick = false;
        $(this).click(function() {
            if (toggleClick) {
                toggleClick = false;
                return off.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            toggleClick = true;
            return on.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').newtoggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked','checked');
    var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
        $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', '');
        var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $(this).val('check all');  
        $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
    }),
     $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        $("#count").html($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length + " item(s) selected")
    })
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usxvb6rb/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but console gives this error `Empty string passed to getElementById().`. Dont know why. But the code works perfectly in 2.1.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already had the solution. Just a few minor changes should do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.check').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("checkedClass");
      var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
      if($(this).hasClass('checkedClass')) {
          checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
      } else {
          checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
      }
       var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
      $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
  });    
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        $("#count").html($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length + " item(s) selected")
  });
});
```

```css
.check {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" id="in1" /><label for="in1"> Checkbox  1</label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" id="in2" /><label for="in2"> Checkbox  2</label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" id="in3" /><label for="in3"> Checkbox  3</label>
</form>
 <p id="count"></p>
```